# connect spring boot with doma2 java

Tags: java

I am just started using java.
And now Im try to connect spring-boot and doma2
here is my code.

AasSampleApplication.java

```java
package com.furkat.aas_sample;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class AasSampleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AasSampleApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    UsersDao reservationDao;

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner runner() {
        return args -> Arrays.asList("spring", "spring boot", "spring cloud", "doma").forEach(s -> {
            Users r = new Users();
            r.name = s;
            reservationDao.insert(r);
        });
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "/")
    List<Users> all() {
        return reservationDao.selectAll();
    }
}
```

User.java

```java
package com.furkat.aas_sample;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Users {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Integer id;
    public String name;

}
```

UserDao.java

```java
package com.furkat.aas_sample;

import java.util.List;
import org.seasar.doma.Dao;
import org.seasar.doma.Insert;
import org.seasar.doma.Select;
import org.seasar.doma.boot.ConfigAutowireable;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@ConfigAutowireable
@Dao
public interface UsersDao {

    @Select
    List<Users> selectAll();

    @Insert
    @Transactional
    int insert(Users users);

}
```

when I run project it says

```
Description:

Field reservationDao in com.furkat.aas_sample.AasSampleApplication required a bean of type 'com.furkat.aas_sample.UsersDao' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
        - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.furkat.aas_sample.UsersDao' in your configuration.
```

I tried some way
*Check the Classpath
*Verify Annotations
*Component Scan Verification
*Check Configuration Class

I could not find what is wrong.
I hope sombody help me to figure out what wrong with my code